# Internal error message for AWSDataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I activated my pipeline that has a simple RDS to S3 copy activity, running on a t1.micro instance, and it failed with the message “Unable to create resource…due to an internal error”. Please refer to the screenshot:
[(Screenshot of failure message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKjD.png)

There’s no logs available either (as you can see in the screenshot). Any pointers on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I see in the screen shot that you canceled the activity.  One thing you can try to unblock yourself is to clone this pipeline and try running it again.

Comment: The "Cancelled" status was assigned by the pipeline itself when it ran into the internal error. It was a bug in the pipeline, for which the work around was to remove the security group field from the EC2 cluster in the architect mode of the pipeline.